# query with lambda expressions and one parameter is null

Tags: c#, lambda, azure-cosmosdb

I want to do a query with lambda expression. 
My database is a Cosmos DB. 
I want to filter for two parameters and one of the two can be null.

For example i want to search for name and lastname and one of both is null.

This is that I am trying:

```
var result = this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_idDatabase, _idCollection), queryOptions)
                    .Where((f) => f.Name == Name && f.LastName == lastName )
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this?

```
var result = this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_idDatabase, _idCollection), queryOptions)
    .Where((f) => (f.Name == Name || (f.Name == null && f.LastName != null)) && (f.LastName == lastName || (f.LastName == null && f.Name != null))
    .AsEnumerable()
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This sentence is very long I want something sorter and more elegant

Comment: Sorry what? Are you expecting us to give you a complete elegant solution for a basic C# question? StackOverflow is not meant for that. You have the pointer, and a valid answer to your question. You can take it from there. A quick refactoring would be to extract the predicate to it's own function and reuse it.

Comment: Maybe this solution works, but I agree to CMorillo that this is not the cleaneast way and hard to maintain. Here, this solution wouldn't pass a code review.

Comment: @SNO It's not meant to. I think you are missing the point. SO doesn't provide complete solutions to requests. It provides answers to questions. Having a property called `Name` and another one `LastName` also wouldn't pass a code review. Same goes for single line if statements like this `if(Name != null) iPerson = iPerson.Where(f => f.Name == Name);`, but that's not the point, is it?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can work with IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<Person> iPerson = this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_idDatabase, _idCollection), queryOptions);

if(Name != null) iPerson = iPerson.Where(f => f.Name == Name);
if(lastName != null) iPerson = iPerson.Where(f => f.LastName == lastName)
return iPerson.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: The CosmosDB SDK doesn't play nicely with the `Equals` method. It throws a NotSupported exception when it does the LINQ to SQL conversion. On top of that, youe queryable will actutually return nothing because a simple `ToList()` won't work. The SDK needs an Enumerable before it can return data with the `ToList` method. It's weird. Also also, he said that he wants the filter to work when one of the two is null not potentially both.

Comment: @nick Chapsas: Ok. To be hornest I haven't worked with CosmosDB SDK, just wanted to give an idea. Sorry for that confusion ;)

Comment: Still not quite what he asked for though. "I want to filter for two parameters and one of the two can be null".

Comment: one of the two **CAN** be null. And what is when both are null or both are set? And again, this should give CMorillo an idea how he can use IQueryable to write clean solutions.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
var result = this._client.CreateDocumentQuery<Person>(
                    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_idDatabase, _idCollection), queryOptions)
                    .Where(f => f.Name == $"{Name ?? f.Name}") &&
                                f.LastName == $"{lastName ?? f.LastName}")  )
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This will not work with CosmosDB as it doesn't support the `like` keyword.

Comment: @NickChapsas how about this one?

Comment: Still doesn't match his question. He said, "I want to filter for two parameters and one of the two can be null.". Your solution can work when both of them are null too.

Comment: So what do you think should happen if both are null?